# java.util.MissingResourceException - Error locating the logging class (MQTT Library)

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I'm writing an Android app that uses MQTT.

On **release** build I get an exception on the line :

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(host, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
```

On **debug** build, all works fine.
I'm using **mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar**.

The execption (that i get in release is) :

```
W/System.err: java.util.MissingResourceException: Error locating the logging class
W/System.err:     at d.a.a.a.a.b.b.a(:2)
W/System.err:     at d.a.a.a.a.e.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
W/System.err:     at c.b.a.j.a(:2)
W/System.err:     at c.b.a.j.<init>(Unknown Source:14)
W/System.err:     at c.b.a.d.onStarted(:1)
W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager$GnssStatusListenerTransport$GnssHandler.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:1424)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I looked inside mqtt library and I found the source code that generates this error :

https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/logging/LoggerFactory.java

Line 76 :

```
    public static Logger getLogger(String messageCatalogName, String loggerID) {
        String loggerClassName = overrideloggerClassName;
        Logger logger = null;

        if (loggerClassName == null) {
            loggerClassName = jsr47LoggerClassName;
        }
        logger = getLogger(loggerClassName, 
        ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageCatalogName), loggerID, null) ;

        if (null == logger) {
                throw new MissingResourceException("Error locating the 
                                                    logging class", CLASS_NAME, loggerID);
        }
    return logger;
    }
```

if I add `debuggable true` in the release block in the file build.gradle I don't get the error and the app works fine. But I don't want a debuggable release.

Can you help me?

Comment: You say this only happens when you run with a production build. Try making sure that the Paho code is excluded from the obfustication.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following lines to the proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.clent.mqttv3.** {*;}
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*$* { *; }
-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.logging.JSR47Logger { *; }
```